# Как использовать Strings.ru.resx из кода?

Tags: c#, локализация

```
Resources
    Strings.resx
    Strings.ru.resx
```

Нужно перевести надпись Connect. Перевод Connect задан в Strings.ru.resx

```
var button = new Button();
button.Content = "Connect";
```

Из XAML это делается так. Но у меня часть кнопок создаются из кода.

```
<Button Content="{l:Localization Key=Free}" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем классе `Strings` все свойства статичные. Можете обращаться к ним из кода

```
Strings.StringKey
```

Если не нужен синглтон, то можно создать экземпляр `ResourceManager`

```
var currentAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var resources = new ResourceManager("StringResource", currentAssembly);

resources.GetString("StringKey", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```